# I wonder to make input components above bottom navigation react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-component, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Hi I have a problem with components styling.

I wonder to make some input components above the bottom navigation similar to [image]

[image]

I'm new at react native,
Maybe you can give some articles or videos to archive that.

Thank you so much

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `NewsFeedScreen` file add bottom view with `position : 'absolute'` and put input inside it
your `NewsFeedScreen` file should returnlike this

```js
return(

  <View style={{flex:1}}>

   //your content here


    <View style={{position : 'absolute', bottom : 0, width : '100%'}}>
       <TextInput/>
    </View>

  </View>

)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm, now I have a problem making an input container above the keyboard after it's shown